# conhost vs. cmd -> Windows registry

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, registry

As I suppose Visual Studio uses `conhost.exe` in the background to execute batch e.g. in pre- or post build event. 
But the windows registry in `conhost.exe` is different to the "normal" windows registry which I can start directly in Windows or via `cmd.exe`. In my case I'm missing some keys under HKLM! 
I created a batch script which only queries (REG QUERY) a key in the windows registry. The batch is working in `cmd.exe` but reports failures in `conhost.exe` for missing keys.

Only one key can exist in a path of the registry, right? But I can create a key in `conhost.exe` registry with no failure which already exists in cmd.exe registry. I thought, the windows registry is unique on my system.

Does anybody know how to break out of the `conhost.exe` environment?
Any attempts on my own are failed. To start a new process doesn't work.

Comment: Registry is different for 32- and 64-bit applications. Make sure that cmd and conhost are of the same bitness.

Comment: Many thanks. Lesson learned. REG QUERY /reg:64 is my solution.